# (DX12) Read-back buffer for 2D-Texture UAV

Tags: memory-management, raytracing, directx-12

I am trying to read-back ray-traced intersections of a ray's recursive path from the GPU to the CPU in DXR.

I am able to render the intersections into a layered unordered access view Texture2D array, so that each layer of the ray-tree corresponds to one layer in this UAV array.

The problem comes when I try to 'readback' this data from the GPU so the CPU can read it. I have not found a way to copy texture information from the GPU to the CPU - I cannot instantiate a 2D-Texture buffer on the read-back heap. I am now looking into writing this intersection information into a flattened 1D UAV buffer - essentially a g-buffer. However, I am having difficulty initializing this (since each pixel may necessarily contain an intersection, I need a buffer the size of the screen-dimensions*RAY_RECURSION_DEPTH (6 in my case), however the number of elements in a UAV-Buffer is limited to size 345599).

Getting to the point, is there a way for me to read-back from a UAV Texture2D resource? Is there a way for me to create a UAV-Buffer with a larger size than 345599? Or, is there another way I should be going about this altogether?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Readback resources for Direct3D 12 must be buffers (`D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_BUFFER`). You create one large enough to hold the Texture2D data (`rowpitch * height`) and then use `CopyTextureRegion` to copy it from the GPU to CPU.

```cpp
D3D12_RESOURCE_DESC bufferDesc = {};
bufferDesc.Alignment = desc.Alignment;
bufferDesc.DepthOrArraySize = 1;
bufferDesc.Dimension = D3D12_RESOURCE_DIMENSION_BUFFER;
bufferDesc.Flags = D3D12_RESOURCE_FLAG_NONE;
bufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_UNKNOWN;
bufferDesc.Height = 1;
bufferDesc.Width = srcPitch * desc.Height;
bufferDesc.Layout = D3D12_TEXTURE_LAYOUT_ROW_MAJOR;
bufferDesc.MipLevels = 1;
bufferDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
bufferDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
```

See [ScreenGrab](https://github.com/microsoft/DirectXTK12/blob/master/Src/ScreenGrab.cpp) and [Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/direct3d12/readback-data-using-heaps)